# Relational Database: Normalization and ERD

Tags: database-design, relational-database, erd

[image: Database Design - First Attempt]

*I am in great fear that this question is not suitable for stackoverflow as it's too specific to my needs and not general enough for the rest of the users, but I thought I'd ask anyway.  If this is not the right place to ask this, please suggest a forum where it would be more fitting.*

I am new to database design, and do not have a teacher to tell me if this is correct or not.

I am setting up a database where a Client can register for a member's only area on website, which can be accessed with a username/password combination.  These members will be sent promotional materials, requiring their mailing address.  According to preliminary surveys, some clients may reside at the same address. Their company name and title within the company is also required.  If the Client is a registered student, they are able to enter the member's area for free, and non-sutdents must pay a fee.

My question: is the attached ERD correct for what I need?  And should I be asking this at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (although it's not exactly code...)

Thanks as always :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your needs are exactly as stated, your ERD should work.  I would suggest adding separate tables to store valid postal codes, prefectures and cities to reduce data duplication and entry errors.